# How to use ifstream of C++ to read from a file using length of the data rather than new line?

Tags: c++

Instead of the ifstream >> terminating reading for a file whenever it finds newline, I would like to read from a file using data size. Is there a way to do this?

Currently I use mystream.read(string, length), but I would like to used the ">>" operator instead of read.

Comment: How about overloading >> operator ?

Comment: From a file into what?  And don't say "anything".

Comment: Please, clarify what you mean by "using data size". The whole file contents? Or an specified amount of bytes?

Answer (score 2):

`.read` is *the* way to do what you're asking.

It doesn't make a huge amount of sense to want to do it with `operator>>` instead, which simply *does not* do this.

Just use `.read`, and move on.

---

**Update** Either that, or I misread your question and Kris is right.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? This reads it into a std::vector.

```
inline void util::operator>>(const std::string &address, std::vector<std::string> &v) throw()
{
    std::ifstream fin;
    fin.open(address.c_str());
    for(std::string s; std::getline(fin, s, '\n'); ) {
        v.push_back(s);}
}
```

Though, that's some old code I wrote about 5 years ago. Not sure if that's a best practice but could, perhaps, be helpful? Ignore me if I mis-understood :)

Comment: He asked the opposite, how to read an specified amount of bytes.

Comment: It just reads in the whole thing which is what I thought the op wanted. It sounded like, to me, that he wanted something that would grab everything. I'm not sure how you'd specify the length like the op currently does if he wants to move to the >> operator...

Comment: I think it's only possible combining stream manipulators, like `std::hex`, with an overloaded `operator>>`.

Comment: That doesn't sound like fun! Perhaps the OP could have been clearer in what he or she needed :)

Comment: Hmm, this may indeed be what the OP means actually. Good job Kris.

Answer (score 0):

operator>> only takes one parameter -- a reference to the destination. Without being able to pass in a length somewhere, you really don't have a choice but to use the .read() method.

Maybe you could override operator>> and pass in a reference your own special class that embeds a length parameter.

This seems like a lot of work just to use the >> syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Well, consider the following if the syntax does not confuse you:

```
char g_buf[MAX_BUFFER_LEN];

// The operator>> does not stop reading until it hits the end of file or the data read equals to specified cnt
istream& operator>>(istream& in, int cnt)
{
    return in.getline(g_buf, cnt, char(6));
}

int main()
{
    ifstream in("e:/a.txt");

    // Reads 200 chars from file and put them in g_buf
    in>>200;

    cout<<g_buf<<endl;

    in.close();
}
```

Comment: This is highly confusing operator abuse.

Answer (score 0):

If you really just want the client code to use `operator>>`, you can write an operator that calls `.read()` by using an intermediate type.

```
class Buffer
{
    char * myData;
    std::size_t mySize;
public:
    Buffer ( char * data, std::size_t size )
      : myData(data), mySize(size)
    {}
    friend operator>> ( std::istream& stream, Buffer& buffer )
    {
        return stream.read(buffer.myData, buffer.mySize);
    }
};
```

This allows you to write:

```
static const std::size_t size = 100;
char data[size];
std::cin >> Buffer(data, size);
```

This can come in useful if you know you'll be reading multiple parts with known lengths, such as in:

```
static const std::size_t header_size =  5;
static const std::size_t stream_size = 20;
static const std::size_t footer_size = 12;
char header[header_size];
char stream[stream_size];
char footer[footer_size];
std::cin >> Buffer(header, header_size)
         >> Buffer(stream, stream_size)
         >> Buffer(footer, footer_size);
```